# Change FileName Download from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I using Azure Shared Access Signature to create Url to redirect download from my Azure, problem is when download is using Original Name of File, I want to change filename when user download to client.

Anyone have solution. 
Thanks

p/s: my Container on Azure is Private permission and I using Asp.net MVC 4

Comment: How is your user downloading the file? Are they directly downloading it from the browser or are they using some custom application for that?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri I return Url to file and using  window.location.href to download

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to change the file name in that case as browser is initiating the download. What you could do is present the link to the user and have them invoke the download operation by using something like "Save Target At" in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Blobs cannot be renamed or aliased. The only thing you can change is the base dns name (which you can map to a custom name).

That said: If you really wanted to present a unique blob for download and not use the current name, you could make a blob copy (a very fast operation within the same data center) to the name you desire, and then offer up a Shared Access Signature to that new blob. After a reasonable amount of time (maybe just beyond expiration of the SAS), you could then delete the extra blob.